# Predict function for svm object in R (e1071 library)

Tags: r, svm, predict

```
data(iris)

ir <- iris[1:100,]

ir$Species <- as.factor(as.integer(ir$Species))

m <- svm(Species ~ ., data=ir)
```

how can I use the 'm' object here to predict WITHOUT using the normal predict().

I know how to get the W and B value but how to use them to get the predictions?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use predict?

Comment: @Teja K: want to use the parameters in 'm' to be migrated to another platform which doesn't support R. So what I am doing is building the model in R and using the coefficients on the other platform.

Answer (score 0):

Following your comment, if the platform where you will use the model supports the PMML standard, then export the full model.

```
library(pmml)

pmml(m)
```

[Generate PMML for svm objects](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pmml/docs/pmml.svm)

Comment: that helps but since i am building multiple models based on an identifier and saving them to the list 'm[[i]]' inside the for loop iterating on 'i'. So 'm' is not a single model but contains about 2000 SVM models.